# Array fills only with latest value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have that weird problem.

Array inside while loop (in my case $smt), does not want to fill up with all the 30 values (there are 30 rows returned by my testing query). It contains only the latest value. I checked the loop and it is okay. It does 30 repeats, and `num_rows` also returns 30. It happens only when i try to fill array which uses a key, for example `$array[$key]`. For example printing inside the loop and using arrays without key work like they should.

Maybe i am missing something, but right now i cannot find the problem.

**CODE:**

```
if($res = $con->prepare($query)) {

    call_user_func_array(array($res,'bind_param'),$bind);

    if($res->execute()) {

        $res -> bind_result($iStopID,$iDate,$iTime,$iOd,$iDo,$iType);

        while ($res -> fetch()) {

            $smt['date']=$iStopID;

        }

        //test
        print_r($smt['date']);


    } else error($con->error);

    $res -> close();

} else error($con->error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the $smt key to be the value of $iDate, you'd have to remove the apostrophes, i.e.

```
$smt[$iDate]=$iStopID;
```

Comment: Holy camoly. I did not see that. I should go to sleep. Deleted my answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Array keys are unique. In your while loop you are assigning $iStopID to your array and using the string '$iDate' as the key:

```
 $smt['$iDate'] = $iStopID;
```

The problem is that you are setting the key every time as the string '$iDate' and not the contents of the variable $iDate. Because of this, you are only getting one key (since they are unique). Try this:

```
 $smt[$iDate] = $iStopID;
```

Hope this helps!